# GridView's UpdateMethod not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, objectdatasource

I've got a GridView that I bind to a ObjectDataSource programmatically, like:

```
ObjectDataSource risks = new ObjectDataSource("Risks", "RetrieveProjectRisk");
risks.TypeName = "Promanto.ProjectRisks";
risks.DataObjectTypeName = "Promanto.ProjectRisk";
risks.SelectMethod = "RetrieveProjectRisk";
risks.DeleteMethod = "DeleteProjectRisk";
risks.InsertMethod = "AddProjectRisk";
risks.UpdateMethod = "UpdateProjectRisk";
risks.SelectParameters.Add("WhereClause", TypeCode.String, "ProjectID  ='PR0002'");
RisksGrid.DataSource = risks;
RisksGrid.DataBind();
```

But when I click the edit button and I then update my values, I firstly get an error that RowUpdating should exist.  When I add it, I'm not sure what to put in it.  Isn't my UpdateMethod "UpdateProjectRisk" suppose to fire automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `ObjectDataSource`, providing the `UpdateMethod` isn't enough.

Your update method will need parameters as to which row to update. 
The gridview does not provide this on its own.

You need to implement the `RowUpdating` to provide the `UpdateParameters` needed to updated your `ObjectDataSource`

Take a look at this [ObjectDataSource Example](http://highoncoding.com/Articles/139_GridView_With_ObjectDataSource.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.  Will try that.
Seems like a lot of work for something simple.  If anyone have a better way of doing this, please post.  Will probably not be a ObjectDataSource then.